# WCF CommunicationException on returning Data

Tags: c#, wcf, api, exception

Here at work we have developed a SOAP WCF API that can be reached from the outside. Because one of the requirements for the API has changed, I wanted to add a new class to this API to generated the correct paths for certain function calls.

Our API is divided into 3 seperate libraries:

- One for the objects
- One for the interfaces
- One for the implementation.

Clients ofcourse get the first two to work with in scripts, the server has all three.

The class I wish to add to the API looks like this:

```
namespace TenForce.Execution.API.Objects.Helpers
{
/// <summary>
/// <para>This interface defines the functionality available in the PathHelper for the API.</para>
/// </summary>
public interface IPathHelper
{
    string ApplicationFolder { get; }   // The HomeDataFolder for the application
    string CompanyHomeFolder { get; }   // The HomeDataFolder for the company.
    string CustomFolder { get; }        // The custom folder for professional services.
    string WikiFolder { get; }          // The WIKI folder to store pages.
    string AddinsFolder { get; }        // The AddinFolder to access the addins.
}
}
```

The actual class implementation looks something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using TenForce.Execution.BUL;
using TenForce.Execution.Framework;

namespace TenForce.Execution.API.Implementation.Helpers
{
/// <summary>
/// <para>This class provides a direct implementation of the IPathHelper for the API implementation
/// and manages all the paths inside the DataHomeFolder structure for the TenForce application.</para>
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class PathHelper : Objects.Helpers.IPathHelper
{
    #region Private Fields

    private readonly ParameterBUL _mParameterBul;
    private const Parameter.ParameterId DataHomeFolderId = Parameter.ParameterId.DataHomeFolder;
    private const Parameter.ParameterId CompanyNameId = Parameter.ParameterId.CompanyName;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Creates a new instance of the PathHelper class</para>
    /// </summary>
    public PathHelper()
    {
        _mParameterBul = new ParameterBUL();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IPathHelper Members

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the DataHomeFolder of the TenForce Application.</para>
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string ApplicationFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(_mParameterBul.GetParameterValue(DataHomeFolderId));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company DataHomeFolder.</para>
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyHomeFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(ApplicationFolder, _mParameterBul.GetParameterValue(CompanyNameId)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company custom folder.</para>
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string CustomFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(CompanyHomeFolder, @"custom"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company wiki folder.</para>
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string WikiFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(CompanyHomeFolder, @"wiki"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company addins folder.</para>
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string AddinsFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(CompanyHomeFolder, @"addins"));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Members

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Checks if the specified path exists, and creates the path 
    /// if the system cannot find it.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to verify.</param>
    private static string CreatePath(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        return path;
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

All by all this is pretty basic stuff. The WCF Service is created dynamicly by us using the Factories and classes available through .NET. The WCF Service is working perfectly for all the code already existing inside the Service.

So I decided to add the following line inside the class that's our Service:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the PathHelper to construct the various paths for API Scripts.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An instance of the PathHelper.</returns>
    public Objects.Helpers.IPathHelper GetPathHelper()
    {
        return new Helpers.PathHelper();
    }

    #endregion
```

When I run the unittests, all tests are working except those that check the functions of the PathHelper, they all end up with the same error message/exception:

> Error 1   TestCase 'TenForce.Execution.API.ImplementationTest/HelperTests/CheckApplicationFolderPath' failed: 
>   Execute
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote endpoint no longer recognizes this sequence. This is most likely due to an abort on the remote endpoint. The value of wsrm:Identifier is not a known Sequence identifier. The reliable session was faulted.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestSessionChannel.SyncRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at TenForce.Execution.API.Contracts.IAPI.GetPathHelper()
>      at TenForce.Execution.API.ServiceClient.ServiceAPI.GetPathHelper() in c:\Users\arne.de.herdt\Documents\Trunk\Robinson\TenForce.Execution.API.ServiceClient\ServiceAPI.cs:line 163
>      at TenForce.Execution.API.ImplementationTest.HelperTests.CheckApplicationFolderPath() in C:\Users\arne.de.herdt\Documents\Trunk\Robinson\TenForce.Execution.API.ImplementationTest\HelperTests.cs:line 56    c:\Users\arne.de.herdt\Documents\Trunk\Robinson\TenForce.Execution.API.ServiceClient\ServiceAPI.cs  163

I'm clueless what's going wrong, or what I'm missing. The code is working for what's already there, but when I added my piece, it goes haywire, yet the existing functions keep working. it's mine that cause a problem.

Comment: +1 for a nice and detailed explanation of the problem

Comment: There was probably some unhandled error on server which aborted the session. Use WCF tracing to get more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Is GetPathHelper OperationContract? In such case you must use KnownType attribute or ServiceKnownType attribute to define which path helper types can be returned.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do... why is your `PathHelper` decorated with `[DataContract]` ?? Are you using that class as a input/output parameter on your service somewhere?? Mind you: for data contract, **only data** gets serialized and passed between server and client - **no functions/behaviors**!  If that class is used in your server-side code only, then there's no point in making it a [DataContract] (don't think that'll cause the exception, though...)

Comment: The PathHelper class does get sent to the client, as it has the functionality to generate paths depending on information in the database. Although it should probably not beeing sent with WCF Service.

Our API can be used in two different ways:

Comment: I'll try to exapnd a bit with information:

The API can be used in two different ways:
1. The firs option is to use the DLLs with a script that is running on the server. We allow the option to write C# scripts and link against the API DLLs to use the functionality there.

Comment: 2. The second option is to use a WCF Service and call specific functions. Basicly we return an IAPI object through the WCFService, and this IAPI object has the function to create an instance of the PathHelper class. This is why I added the datacontract, not sure if I need them.

The tests for situation one work fine. I can call the class directly and generate the paths. If I try to retrieve the instance of the PathHelper through the WCF Service, these exceptions are beeing thrown.

Comment: You can't return object which have a function. You must have the object class on client and only fill its data.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, this PathHelper can only be used in the scripts, which have direct access to the DLL, but I cannot send this object the WCF Service because it has functions ?

Comment: @airslash: yes, exactly - you **cannot** "send back" an object to the client and expect its functions and methods to work - they **won't** since WCF serializes and sends **only the data** - nothing else (not the whole object - just a **data representation** of that object)

Comment: Ok, then I need to discuss this with the team and inform them. Then we probably cannot make this available through WCF, only through the scripts....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the feedback from the comments and the awnser, the solution is to move the class to the second API implementation, and not make it avaialble through the WCF Service.

The class contains functions and read-only properties, thus the class cannot be serialized by the WCF Service. The final result will be that only scripts can use it, and not the service.

Comment: Seemed logical, it is only avaliable to clients

Answer (score 1):

The error seems strange to me, maybe it is related to the way you are dynamically generating the services.

However, that class is not serializable, the properties on that class are read only (do not have a set accessor). For marking a property as DataMember the properties need to have a set accesor, even if it is marked as private. From MSDN:

> Note
>   Properties to which the DataMemberAttribute attribute has been applied must have both get and set fields; they cannot be get-only or set-only.

[DataMember Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx)

The only thing you may want to serialize in that class is the m_ParameterBul variable, so marking that as DataMember and removing all the other DataMember attributes from the readonly properties will do it.

You should note that if m_ParameterBul is not server dependant there is not need to create this class on the server side, because everything is client related. In that case you should create it directly on the clients.

Hope it helps!

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>This class provides a direct implementation of the IPathHelper for the API implementation
/// and manages all the paths inside the DataHomeFolder structure for the TenForce application.</para>
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class PathHelper : Objects.Helpers.IPathHelper
{
    #region Private Fields
    [DataMember]
    private readonly ParameterBUL _mParameterBul;
    private const Parameter.ParameterId DataHomeFolderId = Parameter.ParameterId.DataHomeFolder;
    private const Parameter.ParameterId CompanyNameId = Parameter.ParameterId.CompanyName;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Creates a new instance of the PathHelper class</para>
    /// </summary>
    public PathHelper()
    {
        _mParameterBul = new ParameterBUL();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IPathHelper Members

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the DataHomeFolder of the TenForce Application.</para>
    /// </summary>   
    public string ApplicationFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(_mParameterBul.GetParameterValue(DataHomeFolderId));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company DataHomeFolder.</para>
    /// </summary>   
    public string CompanyHomeFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(ApplicationFolder, _mParameterBul.GetParameterValue(CompanyNameId)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company custom folder.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public string CustomFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(CompanyHomeFolder, @"custom"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company wiki folder.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public string WikiFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(CompanyHomeFolder, @"wiki"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Returns the absolute path to the Company addins folder.</para>
    /// </summary>    
    public string AddinsFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatePath(Path.Combine(CompanyHomeFolder, @"addins"));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Members

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Checks if the specified path exists, and creates the path 
    /// if the system cannot find it.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to verify.</param>
    private static string CreatePath(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        return path;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I've applied the changes as you said, and i'm getting a different error now. I can't paste it completly in here, but it appears to be a timeout now, which is still odd....

I'll try to make the properties with getters and setters, fill in the data on the service and then transmit it.